# How can I open a Activity from a ListView after SearchView filter using an ID stored on a JSON

Tags: java, android, json, listview, searchview

Im new on java and im doing a app for finish my university. This app have a SearchView filtering on a ListView getting data from a JSON. Im almost finishing that but im stuck after the filter part.

After input on the SearchBar and filter returns the result I cant open a new intent getting the ID from the JSON. I only can open the intent using the position ListView number (that doesn't work for my necessity because of filter process).

The image below shows exactly the issue:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPlb3.png)

So my necessity is: Open a intent using the ID stored on the JSON for avoid the issue of changing position ID after filter result.

I dont have any idea how I fix this.

Bean:

```
public class Model {
private String description;
private int id;

public Model(int id, String description) {
    this.setId(id);
    this.setDescription(description);
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener {

private ListView list;
private ListViewAdapter adapter;
private SearchView editsearch;
public static ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList = new ArrayList<Model>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    loadDataJSON();

    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    editsearch = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
    editsearch.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int a = position;
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Info.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("valor", a);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}

public String loadJSON(String arq) {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open(arq);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}



private void loadDataJSON() {
    String arquivo = loadJSON("lista.json");
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(arquivo);
        JSONArray a = obj.getJSONArray("locais");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject item = a.getJSONObject(i);
            Model model = new Model(item.getInt("id"),item.getString("description"));
            modelArrayList.add(model);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    String text = newText;
    adapter.filter(text);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onClose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
public ArrayList<Model> arraylist;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context ) {
    mContext = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Model>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(MainActivity.modelArrayList);
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return MainActivity.modelArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Model getItem(int position) {
    return MainActivity.modelArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;  
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
          holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.name.setText(MainActivity.modelArrayList.get(position).getDescription());
    return view;
}


public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    MainActivity.modelArrayList.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        MainActivity.modelArrayList.addAll(arraylist);
    } else {
        for (Model mp : arraylist) {
            if (mp.getDescription().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                MainActivity.modelArrayList.add(mp);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Info:

```
public class Info extends Activity {

TextView aaa, bbb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);

    aaa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aaa);
    bbb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bbb);

    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    int id = mIntent.getIntExtra("valor",0);

    String arquivo = loadJSON("lista.json");

    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(arquivo);
        JSONArray a = obj.getJSONArray("locais");
        JSONObject item = a.getJSONObject(id);

        aaa.setText(item.getString("id"));
        bbb.setText("Base: "+item.getString("description"));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

public String loadJSON(String arq) {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open(arq);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

JSON:

> { "locais": [{
>   "id": "1",
>   "description": "Text A"
>   }, {
>   "id": "2",
>   "description": "Text B"
>   }]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `int a = modelArrayList.get(position).getId()` instead. So you will get id from JSON

Comment: Ok so this passed the ID by intent but didnt solved the whole problem. Now Text A opens Text B content and Text B crashed and return a out of range. Any idea how can I fix this? UPDATE: Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You need to use that intent in ListViewAdapter 
Hope its works fine